# Session issue while adding items to shopping cart

Tags: php, arrays, session, cart

I have a shopping cart issue in terms of sessions - this codes works, however there is a semantic error on sessions that I could not figure out.

Every time I add an item to the cart instead of adding a new item to the cart or instead of appending it overwrites it. I am intending to have it append on one page that shows all the added items in the cart and its total.

Any help is greatly appreciated thank you. :)

Here is my shoppingcart code page:

```
<?php

    $serverName = "example.com";
    $dbName = "abc1234";
    $user = "abc2345";
    $pass = "bbc334";

    $con = mysqli_connect($serverName, $user, $pass, $dbName);

    if(!$con){
        die("failure to connect to the server  ".mysqli_connect_error());
    }

?> 

<?php session_start();

if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == "add")
{
    $product = intval($_GET['id']);

    if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$product])){
        $_SESSION['cart'][$product]['quantity']++;
} else {
    $accessdata = "SELECT * FROM Software WHERE id = ($product)";
    $newquery = mysqli_query($con, $accessdata);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($newquery)!= 0){
         $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($newquery);
         $_SESSION['cart'][$row2['id']] = array("quantity" => 1,  "cost" =>     $row2['price']);
}else{
     $mes = "Invalid ID";
    }
    }
} error_reporting(0);

?> 
<h2 class="inform"><?php if(isset($mes)){echo $mes;}?></h2>

<?php
//counter quantity
     if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        foreach($_POST as $access => $value){
            $access = explode("-", $access);
            $access = end($access);
            $access = explode("submit", $access);
            $access = end($access);

            if($_POST['quantity-'.$access] <= 0){
                unset($_SESSION['cart'][$access]);
            } else if($_POST['quantity-'.$access] >=50){
                $_SESSION['cart'][$access]['quantity'] = 50;
            }else{
                $_SESSION['cart'][$access]['quantity']=  $value;
            }
        }
    } 

?>  
<h1> View Shopping Cart </h1>
<?php
    $dataaccess = "SELECT * FROM Software WHERE id IN (";
        foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product => $value){
            $dataaccess .= $product. ",";
        }
        $dataaccess = substr($dataaccess, 0, -1).") ORDER BY name  ASC";
        $query = mysqli_query($con, $dataaccess);
        if(empty($query)){
        echo "<br /> Add an item to the cart to proceed "; 
        }
?>

<form method="POST" action="shoppingcart.php">
    <fieldset>
        <table>
                <tr>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Cost</th>
                <th>Total Price</th>
            </tr>
<?php
    $dataaccess = "SELECT * FROM Software WHERE id IN (";
        foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product => $value){
            $dataaccess .= $product. ".";
        }

    $dataaccess = substr($dataaccess, 0, -1). ") ORDER BY name ASC";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $dataaccess);
    $totalcost = 0;
    if(!empty($query)){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            $subtotal = $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id']] ['quantity'] * $row['price'];
            $totalcost += $subtotal;
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['name']; ?> </td>
<td><input type="text" name="quantity-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" size="5"    value="<?php echo $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id']]['quantity']; ?>" /></td>
<td><?php echo "&pound;".$row['price'];?></td>
<td><?php echo "&pound;".$_SESSION['cart'][$row['id']]   ['quantity']*$row['price'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
}
?>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>TOTAL: </td>
    <td><?php echo "&pound;".$totalcost;?></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update Cart" /></fieldset>
</form>
<p>To remove an item, set quantity to 0</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Replace your `error_reporting(0)` by `error_reporting(E_ALL)` to show all errors, it will greatly help you.

Comment: This is bad here: `?> 

<?php session_start();` You have an output before your `session_start()` Move the `session_start()` to the top of your file. This should be the first line.